# MongoDB - slow '$group' performance

Tags: performance, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection of over 1,000,000 records.
Each record size is around 20K (so the total collection size is around 20GB).

I have a 'type' field in the collection (that can have around 10 different values).
I would like to get the per-type counters for the collection.
Also, there is an index on the 'type' field.

I've tested two different approaches (assume python syntax):

## A naive method - using 'count' calls for each of the values:

```
for type_val in my_db.my_colc.distinct('type'):
    counters[type_val] = my_db.my_colc.find({'type' : type_val}).count()
```

## Using aggregation framework with a '$group' syntax:

```
counters = my_db.my_colc.aggregate([{'$group' :  {'_id': '$type', 'agg_val': { '$sum': 1 } }}])
```

The performance I'm receiving for the first approach is about 2 orders of magnitude faster than for the 2nd approach.
Seems to be related to the fact that count runs on the indices only, without accessing the documents, while $group has to go over the documents one-by-one.
(It's about 1min vs. 45mins).

Is there any way to run an efficient grouping query on the 'type' index, that would use only the index, thus achieving the performance results from #1, but using the aggregation framework ?

I am using MongoDB 2.6.1

Update:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11447 is open on this issue in MongoDB Jira.

Comment: Well for one the aggregation framework is not using an index, try adding: {$sort:type} before the group

Comment: Added, doesn't seem to help. If the $group statement still has to access the documents one-by-one, the sort should not make a difference...

Comment: It shouldn't but optimisations are supposed to make it use an index, I do know however that the aggregation framework still cannot use covered indexes but it was worth a try

Comment: I hope MongoDB will add it in future releases. After all, it's a very simple and common usecase...

Comment: How many types are you expecting since using distinct with count (distinct() here can use a covered query) might be ok

Comment: About 10 types. It is ok for my purpose for now, and that's what I'm using, but it makes sense that this would be implementable with a single 'group' query...

Comment: As reference these are the issues that are stopping you: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12015?jql=project%20%3D%20SERVER%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22Aggregation%20Framework%22%20AND%20text%20~%20%22covered%20index%22

Comment: Thanks ! Seems to be very relevant indeed. Although the version in the bug is 2.5.5, and I'm using 2.6.1.

Comment: Yeah it starting in 2.5.5 and it is on going atm, 2.4 can use a covered query here]

Comment: Interesting, so this actually might be a regression, after we upgraded to 2.6

Comment: Indeed, it is, the aggregation framework was changed to use an different approach according to that issue and the issue basically tracks putting it back to a method that can use covered queries, hopefully it will be done soon

Answer (score 4):

in aggregation pipeline the $group clause doesn't use indexes. It is supposed to be used after a $match, which indeed can use indexes to speed it up.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance

cheers,

Comment: ...not much help if you need to group the entire collection as he says

Comment: it seems the most performant way is the multi query one. If you don't need realtime data you can use a cache layer. But you cannot speed it up using aggregation framework.